# Remove/add class on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to remove one class from a div and add another upon the click of a button. But I can't get it to work.

```
<div class="hiddennav displaynone">
  <ul>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav menu')); ?>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- end div hiddennav -->
<div class="fixednav">
  <div class="shownav"><a href="#" class="shownavbutton"></a></div>
  <!-- end div shownav -->
</div> <!-- end div fixednav -->
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".shownavbutton").click(function() {
    $(".hiddennav").removeClass("displaynone").addClass("displayblock");
  });
```

I'd preferably want it to toggle the classes too when clicked multiple times.

Comment: you got far enough to add "want it to toggle the classes"  , but not far enough to google "jQuery toggle class"   because you'd find toggleClass()

Comment: Looks like you're missing an extra `});` to end the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$(selector).toggleClass(class)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".shownavbutton").click(function() { 
        $(".hiddennav").toggleClass("displaynone").toggleClass("displayblock");
    });
});
```

Optionally, you could use the CSS method as well (assuming that this is all you're accomplishing via your `displaynone` and `displayblock` classes):

```
$(".hiddennav").toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".hiddennav").toggleClass("displaynone displayblock");
```